# LaTeX Error with Sphinx: file `titlesec.sty' not found

Tags: python-2.7, python-sphinx, tex

While trying to generate the PDF documentation of a Sphinx project, I get this:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `titlesec.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

I have installed the textlive package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually you only need `texlive-formats-extra` to get 361 MB of archives, instead of 1,500 MB for `texlive-full`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-formats-extra
```

Comment: Package is named differently on pacman: `$ sudo pacman -S texlive-formatsextra`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply install the required package `texlive-titlesec` via yum (if you are using the RPM packet manager):

```
yum install texlive-titlesec
```

Answer (score 2):

I did need to install the **texlive-full** package. It have the **titlesec.sty** file. The **textlive** package does not contains the file.

Comment: Which distro/OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 15.10 at that time

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall MikTeX and install the full MikTeX package (not just the basic package). Took like 10 years to update everything. After that just open a document with LyX and after reconfiguration everything should work.